# Need single http request multi redirection using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, redirect

i need to redirect a single http request to multiple servers.

**res.writeHead(301, {'Location': urlToRedirect1});
res.writeHead(301, {'Location': urlToRedirect2});**

i cant able to redirect using the above code. only the last url(urlToRedirect2) only redirects properly.

Is this possible to redirect multiple servers using res.writeHead. If not can i know the alternative to this.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Single request single response. Might be possible in quantum physics though.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to do this in node js

Comment: How would you expect this to play out in the browser?

Comment: Not in browser ... It's a server side request

Comment: Actually, the 301 redirect is handled by the browser; the server throws an HTTP 301 error, the browser receives that error and redirects to the instructed URL. Also, the HTTP 301 error only admits a single URL to redirect to. There are alternatives, but first we will have to understand what's your intention.

Comment: i am getting an http request from a device in a instance(Server) that instance should forward the request to other 2 instance(Servers)

Comment: for example, i am getting request to this server(aaa.com) this server should forward the request to 2 other servers example bb.com & cc.com

Comment: You mean it should redirect to send to either bb.com or cc.com randomly?

Comment: no. it should forward the same request to both bb.com and cc.com

Comment: That does not even make sense from an HTTP protocol standpoint.
Why do you want to do that, and what are the intended results?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the concept. i need to forward the request to 2 servers. not redirect the request. how to do it in node js using listen.

Comment: Okay... do you intend to forward a request to two servers and then combine their responses?

Comment: I need to just forword the request to two servers no need response them..Please can you give me example codes..

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), from the sounds of the above you don't need redirection; something like the following (note I'm assuming you are receiving a form post and the body of the request is what you need forwarding.

```
function makeRequest(callback){
    var request - require('request');
    var dataToSend = req.body;
    var url1 = 'http://server1/resource';
    var url2 = 'http://server2/resource';

    // Send to server 1
    request.post(url1, dataToSend, function(err, response, body){
        if(err) return callback(err);
        // Make the second call
        request.post(url2, dataToSend, function(err2, response2, body2){
         if(err2) return callback(err2);
         // Both calls are now complete
         callback(null);
    });
}
```

If you need to make more than two calls the code below will get messy so you'd probably want to create a single makeRequest function that receives the URL to call and the data as arguments and call it within a loop